# .htaccess redirect on external linking

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, external, internal

I would like a website to initially display intro.html when coming from external websites like google, or just from typing in the url. This intro.html and all internal links will link to index.php (wordpress blog so index.php can't change filename) which will then serve as the homepage. Can i do this with .htaccess, perhaps some rewritecond only on external links?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just redirect every request that does not come from your website, you can check this with HTTP_REFERER. [This](http://altlab.com/htaccess_tutorial.html) article should get you on the right path.

Comment: Great this is definitively what i need! The website still doesent redirect when i type the address in the address bar, is there a way to include this aswell? This is what i've got:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://mysite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mysite.com/intro.html [R,L]

Comment: @user1250987 you had a solution that you suggested as an edit, please edit your `question` and add it in there as an update.